# In a React-Native app, how to use SwitchNavigator (react-navigator) and react-redux?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation's SwitchNavigator to manage my navigation based on authentication state. When Authenticated, I want to use Redux to store data I'm fetching.

My SwitchNavigator looks like this

```
SwitchRouteConfig = {
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  Authenticated: AppStackNavigator,
  NotAuthenticated: AuthStackNavigator,
}

SwitchConfig = {
  initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
}

export default createSwitchNavigator(SwitchRouteConfig, SwitchConfig);
```

My Authenticated navigation looks like this:

```
// App Bottom Tab Navigator
const AppTabRouteConfig = {
  AddItem: { screen: AddItem },
  Items: { screen: Items },
  Map: { screen: Map },
  Help: { screen: Help },
}
const AppTabConfig = { initialRouteName: 'Items',}
const AppTabNavigator = new createBottomTabNavigator(
                     AppTabRouteConfig, 
                     AppTabConfig)
```

And in my Screen we have:

```
class Items extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getData(); //call our redux action
  }

  render() {
  if(this.props.isLoading){
    return(
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    )
    } else {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <SafeAreaView>
            <FlatList
              data={this.props.dataSource.features}
              renderItem={({ item }) =>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                  <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                    <Text>{item.prop1}</Text>
                    <Text>{item.prop2}</Text>
                  </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              }
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        </Provider>
      )
  }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    isLoading: state.dataReducer.isLoading,
    dataSource: state.dataReducer.dataSource
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
                       mapDispatchToProps)(Items)
```

When I'm not authenticated, that works fine. I can login. When I am authenticated, I get the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" 
in either the context or props of 
Connect(Items)". Either wrap the root 
component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass 
"store" as a prop to "Connect(Items)".
```

In the reading I've done today, all the samples have a single top-level component  which they wrap with . So, I'm not understanding how you instantiate the store and manage Redux without that model.

I should mention two additional things:

1. The initial authenticated app screen worked fine before I started to implement Redux.
2. I'm not trying to manage the state with Redux, just application data.
3. Project started with Create-React-Native-App.

Thank you!

Comment: where is your "Root" component? that's where you should render the `Provider`component

Comment: Yeah, I think that's sort of my question as well... and maybe I'm doing this all wrong honestly. In my App, I have screens for Items, Item, Map Items... Items and Item worked via a Stack Navigator but they are separate Screens (and files). I was working to add a Map view of all Items and that lead me to wanting to use Redux to store the data I fetch in Items.. But there is not 1 component at the top, its all Screens and Navigators. But that seems like a valid approach based on other examples I've seen with react-navigator.

Comment: where are you rendering the `SwichNavigator` component? That's a component, just wrap that component inside `Provider` and everything should work as expected.

Comment: See the first code block above.  `export default createSwitchNavigator(SwitchRouteConfig, SwitchConfig);`

Comment: So that's the component you are passing to `AppRegistry.registerComponent('Your App Name' , () => YourSwitchNavigator);`? Are you using `expo` (that means that you probably don't have to use `AppRegister.registerComponent`)?

Comment: I am using Create-React-Native-App, so yes to expo. (I added a note about that above, and should have included that in the beginning.) And yes, it appears as this is something the framework takes care of.  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component

Comment: yeah I thought that you were not using expo. I added an answer that should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap the root component (the switch navigator) inside `Provider` to make the store available to all container components.

```
const SwitchRouteConfig = {
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  Authenticated: AppStackNavigator,
  NotAuthenticated: AuthStackNavigator,
}

const SwitchConfig = {
  initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
}

const Navigator = createSwitchNavigator(SwitchRouteConfig, SwitchConfig);


// You can use a stateless component here if you want
export default class Root extends React.PureComponent {
   render() {
     return (
        <Provider store={store}> 
           <Navigator />
        </Provider >
     );
   }

}
```